# htaccess redirect index.php?/* to ?/*

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Basically I need to do exactly what the title says.
I have a client site using the following url structures:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/index.php?/<folder>/<file>

http://www.example.co.uk/?/<folder>/<file>
```

I need to redirect index.php?/ to ?/

Cheers for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?/(.*)\ HTTP 
RewriteRule ^ /?/%2 [R=301,L]
```

It should change `index.php?/folder/file` to `?/folder/file`

Comment: Thank you! Never would of considered a solution like that.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If it did help you, you can mark it as correct so other people who have the same question as you will know how you solved it.